# Jquery-UI's _render function not working in autocomplete

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui, autocomplete, jbuilder

I am trying to use the autocomplete function in Jquery-UI. The backend seems to be working. It is printing out the correct objects and returning the correct json object, however, the _render function is not firing.

Javascript:

```
var app = window.app = {};
app.Problems = function() {
  this._input = $('#problems-search-txt');
  this._initAutocomplete();
};

app.Problems.prototype = {
  _initAutocomplete: function() {
    this._input
      .autocomplete({
        source: '/search_for_problems',
        appendTo: '#problems-search-results',
        select: $.proxy(this._select, this)
      })
      .autocomplete('instance')._renderItem = $.proxy(this._render, this);
  },

  _render: function(ul, item) {
    var markup = ['<span class="name">' + item.name + '</span>'];
    console.log("trying to render");
    return $('<li>').append(markup.join('')).appendTo(ul);
  },

  _select: function(e, ui) {
    this._input.val(ui.item.name);
    return false;
  }
};
```

HTML:

```
  <div class="problems-search">
    <input type="text" id="problems-search-txt" autofocus>
    <div class="results" id="problems-search-results"></div>
  </div>

  <script>
     new app.Problems;
  </script>
```

Ruby on Rails

class ProblemsController < ApplicationController

```
  def search_for_problems
    @problems = Problem.search(params[:term])

    logger.debug "there are #{@problems.count} problems with the term"
    @problems.each do |problem|
      logger.debug problem.name
    end
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html
        format.json { @problems = Problem.search(params[:term]) }
      end
  end
end
```

Jbuilder:

```
json.array!(@problems) do |problem|
  json.name problem.name
end
```

Why is the _render function not working?

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code, and it works fine.
Keep in mind, that `_renderItem` method will fire only when you'll try to type something in input, and appropriate value (or values) will be found in list of values. In other words you `_render` method will be invoked only when control shows drop down list of source's values.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem as you, with exactly the same code (may be we found the same tutorial...)

I had to change the line

```
.autocomplete('instance')._renderItem = $.proxy(this._render, this);
```

to

```
.autocomplete().data("ui-Autocomplete")._renderItem = $.proxy(this._render, this);
```

It should work if you use a recent version of jQuery UI (1.10+)